# How can I use Amazon's API in PHP to search for books?

Tags: php, api, object, amazon-web-services

I'm working on a Facebook app for book sharing, reviewing, and recommendations. I've scoured the web, searched Google using every search phrase I could think of, but I could not find any tutorials on how to access the Amazon.com API for book information.

I signed up for an AWS account, but even the tutorials on their website didn't help me one bit. They're all geared toward using cloud computing for file storage and processing, but that's not what I want.

I just want to access their API to search info on books. Kind of like how http://openlibrary.org/ does it, where it's a simple URL call to get information on a book (but their databases aren't nearly as populated as Amazon's).

Why is it so hard to find the information I need on Amazon's AWS site? If anybody could help, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could let Zend Framework do the work for you using [Zend_Service_Amazon](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.service.amazon.html).
From what I see it's fairly easy to use, and for simple queries the examples should be enough.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for! I found a PHP class made in 2003 that had zero documentation and therefore impossible to figure out without reading the code line-by-line.

Thanks again!

Comment: Do you still have that PHP class? I'm looking to do something very similar to what you are doing.

Comment: @juan - the link you gave is expired !!!

Comment: It can now be found here: https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.service.amazon.html

Comment: @TerranRich updated! thanks

Answer (score 8):

The reason you weren't finding what you wanted with the AWS APIs is that AWS doesn't have anything to do with Amazon.com's shopping experience.

[AWS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Web_Services) is the cloud service layer that their website is built upon, which they have externalized so others can build upon it as well. As has been mentioned, you want the affiliate advertising stuff.

Answer (score 6):

You want to be looking at their affiliate program, which now appears to be under "advertising". As I recall, it's free to sign up and it works on a referral commission basis. There is nothing specifically for books, you would need to lookup the category ID for books, then you can query on that. There API is pretty extensive and has specific "fields" for different types of product.

https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html

I used the Amazon API for a Facebook app at my last job called Gift-O-Matic (terrible name), that included books from Amazon as a category. The Zend Amazon lib is a good start, but I found it too verbose and rolled my own.