# How can I find where Zend is installed on my server?

Tags: php, zend-framework, include, runtime-error

I'm trying to use Zend's "Zend_Service_Amazon" class in my php script, but I'm not sure where it is installed.  I'm assuming I need to include the path to Zend before trying to call methods based on this error I get:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Service_Amazon' not found in /public_html/path/zend.php on line 3
```

I know Zend is installed based on the `php -v` output of:

```
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.2.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2012, by ionCube Ltd., and
    with Zend Optimizer v3.3.9, Copyright (c) 1998-2009, by Zend Technologies
```

So how do I find out where it resides and how to include it in my php script?

If it makes a difference, I'm using cPanel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Based on the `php -v` output we can say that `Zend Optimizer` is installed. Nothing about `Zend Framework` there
2. Zend Framework is a set of php scripts, nothing else. You don't need to have it installed on the server
3. There is no way rather than finding through all the filesystem if ZF is installed somewhere
4. As long as it is a good idea to rely on a particular software version - just distribute your script *with* zend framework

Comment: ok i think i get it... thought zend framework was a parent of the optimizer... so based upon the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966327/using-zend-service-amazon all i have to do is grab those php files and include them?

Comment: @CheeseConQueso: yes. **any** php library is just a bunch of php files and can be distributed with your project (from technical point of view, not legal)

Comment: @CheeseConQueso: Btw, personally I just add ZF files one by one, iteratively satisfying its dependencies. So I don't always have the complete ZF installation in each project

Comment: ok so i tried a couple things with `require_once` and `include` and im just getting a big ass blizzard/syntax error... after i try to require and/or include i cant even `echo` anything.. and no im not missing the semicolon.. any idea what the error is?

Comment: `require_once('Amazon.php');` and `include 'Amazon.php';` were my attempts... i think syntax is ok

Comment: the directory is password protected.. does that matter?

Comment: @CheeseConQueso: you need to add Zend Framework directory to include path

Comment: can i do that via the php script or do i have to edit php.ini?

Comment: ok thanks.. i got past the blizzard.  i have more fatals but i see what the deal is now. thanks

Answer (score 4):

The [Zend Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zend_Engine) is the interpreter for PHP and has nothing to do with the Zend Framework.

The Zend Framework is probably not installed on your server unless you have installed it yourself. See the [quick start](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html) for more information and instructions on where and how to install Zend Framework.