# How to use Zend Service Amazon?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, codeigniter, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I've been doing a lot of digging around and have ended up with a huge headache and no success. I am trying to use the Zend Amazon Service (within my **Codeigniter** framework) to fetch information about a book using its ISBN. I initially tried it with Zend 1.12 but I kept getting an error about missing parameter AssociateTag. I am now trying with Zend 2.0 but still getting problems.

This is the code I am using within my controller:

```
    set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'site/libraries');
    require_once 'Zend2/Loader/StandardAutoloader.php';
    $autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
    $amazon = new Zend_Service_Amazon('[apikey]', 'US', '[secretkey]');
    $item = $amazon->itemLookup('B0000A432X');
```

I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Loader_Autoloader' not found.

My questions are:

- How can I load the correct autoloader?
- Where do I include the associate tag in the parameters? There is no mention of it in the outdated zend user guide
- Zend 2.0 doesn't even seem to have the amazon service files or even the /service folder. What does this mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note:** The demo included with zendservice-amazon doesn't work as is.  Requests *must* include your App ID, Secret Key, and Associate Tag which the demo script doesn't do by default.  It took me a while to figure this out, without these, all queries throw an exception saying the HTTP response status was 400.  Unfortunately the exception doesn't have the response body which says what parameters were missing.

Here is some code that will get you started with ZF2 and `ZendService\Amazon`.

To start, let me outline the directory structure of where I will be putting files for this example:

```
testing
|-Zend
|---Crypt
|---Escaper
|---Http 
|---I18n
|---Loader
|----+AutoloaderFactory.php
|----+... more files
|----+StandardAutoloader.php
|-----Exception
|---Stdlib
|---Uri
|---Validator
|-ZendRest
|-ZendService
|---Amazon
|-----Authentication
|-------Exception
|-----Ec2
|-------Exception
|-----Exception
|-----S3
|-------Exception
|-----SimpleDb
|-------Exception
|-----Sqs
|-------Exception
|----+AbstractAmazon.php
|----+...more files
|----+SimilarProduct.php
|-+test.php
```

The gist is I have created a directory called `testing` where we will place the ZF2 autoloader as well as the Amazon classes and their dependencies.  Under testing is a `Zend` folder that contains the autoloader (in `Loader`) and also a `ZendService` folder where the `Amazon` service goes.

First, we need to get a copy of the autoloader from ZF2.  Part of the reason you were having trouble is because it looks like you are using the ZF1 autoloader which is incompatible with ZF2.  To get the Autoloader from ZF2, you can [download](http://framework.zend.com/downloads/latest#ZF2) the latest ZF2 package and copy the `Loader` directory from `ZendFramework-2.0.x/library/Zend/` into the `Zend` folder we created in the `testing` directory.

Now that we have the autoloader files, let's grab the Amazon service files.  I'll write a detailed answer on how to use Composer to get the latest package, but for now I'll explain how to get it manually.  To get the full list of available ZF2 packages, load up the JSON file at http://packages.zendframework.com/packages.json  In it find, `zendframework/zendservice-amazon`, determine the highest version available from the list, and grab the corresponding dist. *EDIT* As of 11th Jul 2013, this is the latest [zendservice-amazon](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendService_Amazon/archive/master.zip) package.

From the `library` directory in `ZendService_Amazon-2.0.2.zip`, copy the entire `ZendService` directory into the `testing` directory.  You now have the ZF2 Amazon service files.

Next, take care of the dependencies.  From the ZF2 library, copy the directories, `Crypt`, `Escaper`, `Http`, `I18n`, `Json`, `Stdlib`, `Uri`, and `Validator` into the `Zend` directory inside `testing`.

You will also need the [ZendRest](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendRest/archive/master.zip) package.  Copy the `ZendRest` folder from `library` from the ZendRest package to `testing/ZendRest`.

Now for some code.  Create `test.php` inside the `testing` folder with the following contents:

```
<?php

require_once './Zend/Loader/StandardAutoloader.php';

$autoloader = new Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader(array(
    'namespaces' => array(
        'Zend'        => dirname(__FILE__) . '/Zend',
        'ZendRest'    => dirname(__FILE__) . '/ZendRest',
        'ZendService' => dirname(__FILE__) . '/ZendService',
     ),
     'fallback_autoloader' => true));

$autoloader->register();

$tag       = 'prdesign-20'; // replace with your Amazon app ID
$appId     = '1JT2V3QNEHDAMKYR5F02'; // replace w/ your access key from https://portal.aws.amazon.com/gp/aws/securityCredentials
$secretKey = 'Qgjeiw39f8UNzjJgeerrgDs1a193du/v7djDAtn/x';

$query  = new ZendService\Amazon\Query($appId, 'US', $secretKey);
$query->Category('Books')->Keywords('PHP')->AssociateTag($tag);
$result = $query->search();

foreach($result as $item): ?>
<div class="item">
  <a href="<?php echo $item->DetailPageURL ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $item->Title ?></a>
  by <?php if (is_array($item->Author)): ?>
  <?php echo implode(', ', $item->Author) ?>
  <?php else: ?>
  <?php echo $item->Author ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

First, we `require_once` the `StandardAutoloader` class from ZF2.  Once the autoloader is registered, this is the only class you have to manually include.

Next, we create a new autoloader and pass some options.  This tells the autoloader where classes in the namespace `Zend` and `ZendService` are located.  We tell the autoloader they live in the respective folders in our current directory.  Change `dirname(__FILE__)` to the correct path as needed.  The `fallback_autoloader` option tells the autoloader to look for classes of any namespace or vendor in the `include_path`.

Calling `$autoloader->register();` then actually registers the autoloader we set up within PHP.  Setting up the autoloader is now finished.

The next 3 lines define some required parameters for the API.

The next 3 lines are straightforward, we now create a new instance of `ZendService\Amazon\Query` and pass our Amazon app ID and secret key.  We then build the query by specifying to search in the Books `Category` and set the `Keywords` to be PHP.  We also add the required AssociateTag.  Finally, we execute the search.

I <strike>haven't yet used `ZendService\Amazon` yet so I</strike> can't provide detailed instructions on using the class but the included demo script should get you started with sending basic queries to Amazon and processing the results.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Couldn't have asked for a better answer, thanks! Just tried it and it works.

Comment: Just one more thing, would you happen to know the correct syntax to do an item lookup using ISBN? I can't seem to figure it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12971292/how-to-do-itemlookup-with-zend-service-amazon

Comment: what if I dont want to enter the category in search , should I send it with blank quotes ? or is it mandatory to to mention the category ??

Comment: @Deepanshu Try just changing it to $query->Keywords('PHP')->AssociateTag($tag);  I didn't test to see if it would throw an exception if you do not specify category.

Comment: do I have to first register at Product Advertising API, is it paid or free of cost ? actually I have never worked on apis before. All I need is product name, image and description, its for a social networking sites, I'll show the products as interests

Comment: @Deepanshu I believe you do need to register to use the API, but its free as far as i know.

Comment: @drew010 thanks drew, its working absolutely fine...one last thing, i went through the documentation , it returns only 10 records per page and somehow only one page, is there any way one can increase it, I wanna show the records in pagination, else I'll have to call the api on every next click again and again, instead of binding whole data at once

Answer (score 1):

i have use Amazon AWS S3 bucket along with Zend Framework. A simple example is photo upload to amazon AWS Bucket.In you `application/config/application.ini` file

```
;AWSAccessKeyId= "AccessKey"
;AWSSecretKey= "SecretKey"
;AWSS3BucketName = "zoshare-images"
;AWSS3GetImageUrl = "http://[name].s3.amazonaws.com/[folder]/"
```

Lets say you want to upload an image to bucket, below is sample code of controller

```
public function updateAction()
    {
if($_FILES["fuPic"]["size"] > 0 || $_FILES["fuPre"]["size"] > 0)
        {
            $config = Zend_Registry::get('config');

            $s3 = new Zend_Service_Amazon_S3($config['AWSAccessKeyId'],$config['AWSSecretKey']);

            $bucketName =  $config['AWSS3BucketName'];

            if($_FILES["fuPic"]["size"] == 0)
                unset($_FILES["fuPic"]);
            else if($_FILES["fuPre"]["size"] == 0)
                unset($_FILES["fuPre"]);

            $s3->removeObject($bucketName."/[folder]/".$campaignModel->getCampaignId().'_pic_'.$campaign_olddata->getPicture());
            $s3->removeObject($bucketName."/[folder]/".$campaignModel->getCampaignId().'_pre_'.$campaign_olddata->getPreview());


            if (isset($_FILES["fuPic"]))
            {
                $filename = $campaignModel->getCampaignId().'_pic_'.$_FILES["fuPic"]['name'];
                $s3->putObject($bucketName."/[folder]/".$filename, file_get_contents($_FILES["fuPic"]["tmp_name"]),
                    array(Zend_Service_Amazon_S3::S3_ACL_HEADER =>
                    Zend_Service_Amazon_S3::S3_ACL_PUBLIC_READ));
                $data['picture'] = $_FILES["fuPic"]['name'];
            }

            if (isset($_FILES["fuPre"]))
            {
                $filename = $campaignModel->getCampaignId().'_pre_'.$_FILES["fuPre"]['name'];
                $s3->putObject($bucketName."/[folder]/".$filename, file_get_contents($_FILES["fuPre"]["tmp_name"]),
                    array(Zend_Service_Amazon_S3::S3_ACL_HEADER =>
                    Zend_Service_Amazon_S3::S3_ACL_PUBLIC_READ));
                $data['preview'] = $_FILES["fuPre"]['name'];
            }
        }
}
```

Happy Coding !!!!