# How to do ItemLookup with Zend Service Amazon?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, api, codeigniter, zend-framework2

I would appreciate if anyone could guide me on the correct way on doing an ItemLookup by ISBN using the Zend Amazon Service module (with Zend 2.0).

Here is my attempt:

```
    $query  = new ZendService\Amazon\Query($appId, 'UK', $secretKey);
    $query->Category('Books')->IdType('ISBN')->ItemID('978-0321784070')->AssociateTag($tag);
    $result = $query->ItemLookup();
```

But I get the following errors:

- Missing argument 1 for ZendService\Amazon\Amazon::itemLookup(), called in D:\wamp\www\site\controllers\dev.php on line 122 and defined
- Undefined variable: asin

There is no way I can define the ASIN because the only information I will have is the ISBN.

I have already consulted the Zend Service Amazon user guide in the zend framework website but it is outdated and doesn't demonstrate how to do an ISBN lookup. I have also looked at the demo that came with the zend amazon package but that only details how to do item searches, not lookups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to get the ISBN search working, it took me a little while to get it figured out as well.  The problem was that in order to search for ISBN you must use the `ItemLookup` method rather than the `ItemSearch` method which was getting set by the `query()` method.

There may be a better way to get this to work using the OO interface but I haven't tried that yet.

```
$query  = new ZendService\Amazon\Query($appId, 'US', $secretKey);
$item   = $query->itemLookup('9780321784070',
                             array('SearchIndex'   => 'Books',
                                   'AssociateTag'  => $tag,
                                   'IdType'        => 'ISBN',
                                   'ResponseGroup' => 'Small',));
```

Searching by ISBN should return a single `ZendService\Amazon\Item` object rather than an array of results.  Also be aware, if you search by ISBN-13, you need to strip the `-` from the number or it won't find a match.

Credit to this [blog post](http://manas.tungare.name/blog/howto-obtain-metadata-for-a-book-given-its-isbn-using-amazon-web-services-in-php/) by Manas Tungare which hinted to me that we need to use IteamLookup instead of ItemSearch.