# Amazon api book search - PHP

Tags: php, api, search, amazon-web-services

I'm working on a project for school, and what I want is to search books related to some keywords (php, security, ...) on amazon. Then retrieve some informations like how many results are there and the link of the search page,...

I googled a lot and found many libraries that doesnt work anymore, or new ones that require ASSOCIATE_TAG and API_KEYS, I already subscribed and got the API_KEYS, but there's noway for me to get the ASSOCIATE_TAG !!

So i'm asking here, besides scrapping, is there any easy way to do what I explained above.

Thank you in advance

PS: Feel free to ask any additionnal informations

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use Amazon's API in PHP to search for books?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954264/how-can-i-use-amazons-api-in-php-to-search-for-books)

Comment: @MarcB, As I said, the api has changed since late 2011... I already checked the solutions posted there, and still not working...

Comment: For getting associate tag you need to sign up for affiliate program:https://affiliate-program.amazon.co once you join here you will find associate tag at top left.

Comment: @JayaVishwakarma, I'm a student, i'm no a merchant, so I don't think i'll get into that... I'm needing this as a part of a school project, and they're asking information about my website, and what I sell through... Or should I try to explain to them ? maybe :/

Comment: @Enissay, Seems like they made ASSOCIATE_TAG as required parameter. There is nothing like you can use that associate tag only for the website you mentioned while creating the associate tag.So try and create.Here you will find more info http://associates-amazon.s3.amazonaws.com/scratchpad/index.html